# window onbeforeunload not working on second time while we select the Leave page as first time in Chrome

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, google-chrome

I am using window.onbeforeunload Java Script , for while you close the tab in Chrome need to show the pop up as Leave Page or Stay . But the window.onbeforeunload is working in IE and not working in the **Chrome "Version 63.0.3239.132 ".**

And i have attached my code below

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
   return "Hi";
 };
```

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/a1vvo06z/ note that you have to right click in the result frame and choose 'reload frame' to see it working. Note that Chrome will only ask you to confirm leaving the page, it won't show `Hi`. There's nothing you can do about that

Comment: As you send the link  jsfiddle.net/a1vvo06z its working on first time , while we select an Leave means at next time the pop was not showing. Can u give some example that work in the Chrome @RoryMcCrossan